# can't start new intent within onActivityResult Android

Tags: android, camera

I have a button that starts the camera intent then should send the photo to another activity. I used the onActivityResult event to receive the photo then start another intent that should display that photo in full size. However, the other intent is never started despite no errors. Here is the relevant code:

```
    private void openBackCamera() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
    File file = new File(pictureImagePath);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = getSharedPreferences("My Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("imagepath", pictureImagePath); //add item Color with the selected color code
    editor.commit();
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("My Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String imagepath = preferences.getString("imagepath", "");
        File file = new File(imagepath);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
        Intent i = new Intent(CameraExampleActivity.this, Betengan.class); 
        i.putExtra("photo", myBitmap);
        CameraExampleActivity.this.startActivity(i);
 }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Capture Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Have `Betengan` load the bitmap. Do not attempt to pass the bitmap via extras from `CameraExampleActivity` to `Betengan`, as the bitmap will be much too large.

Comment: Thanks a bunch sir, this seems to be the problem. I'll give it a try. Thanks again.